# Excel Convert Time HH:MM:SS to Time elapsed MM:SS

Tags: sql, excel, time-format

The data I have is formated as HH:MM:SS where the seconds are all 00, so a time like

```
     12:22:00
```

Should be

```
     00:12:22
```

Is there a way I can convert this over in excel?

**EDIT:**

Probably a better example.

A time of zero.  So that means no time was elapsed shows up as

```
 12:00:00 AM
```

Instead OF

```
  00:00 (MM:SS)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well its recording zero time as 12:00:00 AM which is misleading as it is now.

Comment: I rephrased my question for clarification good point though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just divide your times by 60.

Put 60 in a cell, copy it, select the range you want and pastespecial with divide.  Also you should just paste values if you want to keep your formatting.

Gordon

Comment: I rephrased my question.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you want to change and run this:

```
Sub FixTime()
Dim r As Range
For Each r In Selection
    v = r.Value
    h = Hour(v)
    m = Minute(v)
    r.Value = TimeSerial(0, h, m)
Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't have access to the VBA section.